# Python re.sub query parsing

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing a query where the 'AND' operator is implicit (I mean when there is a white space between 2 words or 2 brackets or 1 word and a bracket i should place an ' AND ' there). When i got ') (' it's easy to match and replace but i got a problem when facing with a 'wordexample (' or 'wordexample1 wordexample2'. Take in account that 'OR' operator is not implicit so i only need to parse lower case letter words.

An example:

```
a='abc def (ghi) OR jkl'
```

Should look like: `amodif='abc AND def AND (ghi) OR jkl'`

I've tried using re library with that:

```
print re.sub('[a-z] \\(', '[a-z] AND \\(',a)
```

But it changes the last letter of the word with [a-z]. Is there anyway to keep a part of the matching expression (the last letter of the words in this case) with re? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are trying to get something like [`([a-z]) ([(a-z])`](https://regex101.com/r/gC8uZ8/2) (to replace with `\1 AND \2`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a *capturing* mechanism that lets you restore matched and replaced parts using *backreferences*.

Here is a working regex:

```
([a-z]) ([(a-z])
```

Replacement is `\1 AND \2`, where `\1` points to the substring captured with `([a-z])` and `\2` references to the subtext captured with `([(a-z])`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gC8uZ8/2)

[Python code](https://ideone.com/0gNg8i):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([a-z]) ([(a-z])')
test_str = "abc def (ghi) OR jkl"
subst = r"\1 AND \2"
result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
print(result) # => abc AND def AND (ghi) OR jkl
```

Comment: I understand that the solution may be a bit different if the requirements are a bit more precise, however, the basic idea should be the same. Alternatively, a lookaround could be used in a more complex scenario.

Comment: It works fine for me. I didn't know about backreferences. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Another try may be using double `re.sub` if you want to avoid backreference. Where first `re.sub` replaces all white spaces by `AND` and second `re.sub` replaces `\s+AND OR AND\s+` by `OR` to correct it.

So `re.sub(r'(\s+)',r' AND ',s)` returns `'abc AND def AND (ghi) AND OR AND jkl'` and `re.sub(r'\s+AND OR AND\s+',' OR ',re.sub(r'(\s+)',r' AND ',s))` corrects it to `abc AND def AND (ghi) OR jkl`.

**Working example as below-**

```
>>>s='abc def (ghi) OR jkl'
>>>re.sub(r'\s+AND OR AND\s+',' OR ',re.sub(r'(\s+)',r' AND ',s))
>>>'abc AND def AND (ghi) OR jkl'
```

Comment: the problem with that solution is that there are terms in the query that can be "word1 word2" and that implementation would place an AND inside the term i guess. Thanks for the effort anyway

Comment: Ah! if word1 word2 is like `abc AND def AND (ghi) OR jkl abc AND def AND (ghi) OR jkl` then `([a-z]) ([(a-z])` will also place `AND` inside them??